# How to know which class and method a custom coldfusion tag is referring to?

Tags: coldfusion

I have a custom coldfusion tag <cfx_tag1 name="name1" appid="appid1">
In this how should I know the class and method. Please help me with some guidance as to how to proceed.

Comment: The class and method of what?

Comment: https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/developing-applications/building-blocks-of-coldfusion-applications/building-custom-cfxapi-tags/approaches-to-debugging-java-cfx-tags.html

Comment: The class in Java which it is referring to. See cfx_abc means abc is probably a Java based class. So how to know which method of class it is referring to? Also from internet I came to know that in Coldfusion Administrator we specify the class name. But then we do not specify the method name there.

Comment: I googled "java cfx tag" and the first match was ""Writing a Java CFX Tag" (https://helpx.adobe.com/uk/coldfusion/developing-applications/building-blocks-of-coldfusion-applications/building-custom-cfxapi-tags/writing-a-java-cfx-tag.html), and it seems to me the method name will always be `processRequest`, and the class name is likely to be the same as the tag name (although it sounds like in the CF admin UI for registering tags that poss one can use a different name from the class file? Why are you actually asking?

Comment: Also, if this is a Java based CFX tag, which should be a JAR file, why use it as a CFX tag? Can't you load the JAR into CF's path and then just reference it like any other java library with the `new` operator or `createObject()`?